# Retrieve values from database table in yii2-app-basic

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I'm not getting how to retrieve "id" from this query.

```
$post = Yii::$app->request->post('Users');
$params = [':UserMailID' => $post['email']];

$ResendCommand=Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=:UserMailID")
                            ->bindValues($params)->queryOne();
```

I want 'id' from this query. 'id' is one column of USERS table.
Any Idea.

Comment: If you do `var_dump($ResendCommand);`, what would it say?

Comment: Hey sorry @dave. I edited my question. Instead of 'id', i  gave *. Now how to retreive 'id'. Sorry for writing wrong.

Comment: ok, but anyway what the resulting `$ResetCommand` looks like? Do `var_dump()` on it please

Comment: It's showing @dave array(17) { ["id"]=> string(2) "12" ["first_name"]=> string(6) "danish" ["last_name"]=> string(4) "enam" ["email"]=> string(22) "dnsh@otech.com" ["password"]=> string(40) "b153ceb9ad6ccc54d6e77a52cc142ffff639357a" ["user_type"]=> string(1) "1" ["company_name"]=> string(0) "" ["status"]=> string(1) "1" ["auth_key"]=> string(0) "" ["confirmed_at"]=> string(1) "0" ["unconfirmed_email"]=> s ..

Comment: yeah @dave. Upper comment please.

Comment: You gave me idea Mr @dave. Now, I've to do $idd=$ResendCommand['id']; Thanks

Comment: Now working Mr @dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting `id` you use this syntax,

```
<?php

echo $ResendCommand['id'];

?>
```

Comment: Yeah. Thanku Gamitg. I got it.  After posting question. I got idea little. Mr @Dave gave his contribution.